# db.Query does not recognize a var

Tags: c#, razor, var

I have defined variables earlier in my view with

```
var ___ = "____"
```

I have defined these variables: querypeople, where, city, lo, app, order.

In the db.query below, it recognizes querypeople and order, but I do not know why it does not recognize the others, or how many of them it does recognize

```
@foreach (var row in db.Query(querypeople,where,city,lo,app,order))
```

Is there a reason why it would not recognize some of these variables?

I have tried something like this

```
<h3>@querypeople@where@city@lo@app@order</h3>
```

and I see exactly what I would like to see.

All help appreciated!

Comment: Can you paste what the compiler is telling you?

Comment: I don't get an error, it just does not use the var

Comment: I got it! I will post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I was using commas when I should be using addition symbols.

```
@foreach (var row in db.Query(querypeople + where + city + lo + app + order))
```

This gave me what I was looking for. If anyone has an explanation, please share!